# I just want to know if two sentences below are using the word interesting correctly?

Tags: meaning-in-context

1. I am  interesting to read the book.
2. The book I am reading is interesting.

Comment: I wonder why this particular word puzzles non-English speakers so much?

Comment: @KateBunting I wonder if most other languages use the comparable verb in the "opposite direction", so to speak, like "I interest in this book"?  Kind of like how the Spanish *gustar* throws some English learners because when you translate "I like this book" into Spanish, the book is actually the subject performing an action on you as the object.

Comment: @KateBunting for instance in Spanish _aburrido_ not only means bored but also boring.

Answer (score 0):

interested describes a person who has a feeling of wanting to learn more about something, and interesting describes the thing that makes someone feel that way. You feel interested in something because that thing is interesting.
According to the above explanation
Sentence 1 should be
I am interested (not interesting) to read the book
But Sentence 2 is correct

Comment: Sossina, please don't answer your own questions.

Comment: @KateBunting - what makes you think people should not answer their own questions? There is guidance on doing so in every Stack's help section - [Can I answer my own question?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) There is even a space to do this as you're asking the question so both can be posted simultaneously. You can even accept your own answer, after an enforced wait. The answer will be subject to the same voting process as any other.

Comment: @gonefishin'again. - Oh, sorry - I wasn't aware of that.

Answer (score 0):

The second one is correct however the first one is not.

For the first one it should be “I am **interested** to read the book”.

Some examples of sentences which show the use of “interesting” and “interested” are:

“This book looks very **interesting**”

“That documentary was quite **interesting** to watch”

“I am **interested** in purchasing a new car”

“Would you be **interested** in going to the movies with me?”

Comment: I'd far prefer 'interested in reading' over 'interested to read'. The latter sounds very uncomfortable to me as a native.